# Protected usernames

Tags: discussion

Could we have some protection on usernames such as "Community", the name, along with a display picture, could lead to misinterpretation of the poster.

Question example: [Join first table with latest record of second table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47693719/join-first-table-with-latest-record-of-second-table)

User: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3664659/community

In the feed:

[image: feed]

Comment: The diamond (or lack thereof) is the protected distinguishing feature.

Comment: @RobertLongson I know, but I feel it doesn't detract from the fact having the username as `Community` or `Admin` or something along those lines adds unnecessary confusion.

Comment: @SamuelLiew _technically_ Community is a name of an actual user account of a bot. Even the image is the same here. So, I dont think it is quite the same as having a username as StackOverflow/Moderator..

Comment: This is impersonation, plain and simple. I've flagged the linked question explaining the situation, and also linking back here. As explained in the dupe, it's practically impossible to block certain usernames. Just flag them.

Comment: @Cerbrus based on name and avatar I assume? There are two other users with that name but they have different avatars.

Comment: @rene: Yea, the combination makes it clear the user is aware of the Community bot's existence, and has purposefully copied the account's information. The other 2 don't have the same profile image (and haven't been active in years), so that could be coincidence.

Comment: The flag appears to have been successful. The user's name and profile image have been reset.

Comment: You are not Ron Jeremy. Your avatar is invalid. Please change it.

Comment: @Will I might be!